# Why is "lawyer" widely pronounced "loyer"?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

This pronunciation phenomenon appears to be more widespread than I'd thought.  I've always pronounced *lawyer* as it's spelled (**law**-yer), but I've often heard people say ***loy***-er instead.  It's not dialectical as far as I can tell, since so many different people say it that way (plus, it's [in the dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lawyer)).  Why is *lawyer* so often pronounced *loyer*?

Comment: Why is *oil* widely pronounced *oyel*?  Probably a similar principle.

Comment: I don't know, but it's probably related to whatever caused Bowyer to be pronounced *boyer*.

Comment: So it will rhyme with "sawyer"?

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, lawyer, sawyer and bowyer can all rhyme. But some families pronounce their surnames differently: *Soy-ur, Saw-yur, Boy-ur, Bow-yur* are all correct.

Comment: @GEdgar:  How else could you possibly pronounce it? *Oil* isn't spelled *awyel*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OED has both /ˈlɔːjə(r)/ and /ˈlɔɪə(r)/.  In my British accent, I tend towards the second. The reason it’s so widespread, if indeed it is, may be because the transition to the vowel /ə/ (schwa) is more readily made from the diphthong /ɔɪ/ than it is from the sequence of /ɔː/,  /j/, but I readily yield on the point to any phoneticians among us.

Comment: That’s basically it. The unusual /-awy-/ [ɔːj] shifts to the more conventional /oi/ [ɔɪ] or [ɔj].

Comment: Except I'm not sure it's so unusual.

Comment: @Jon: Barrie's right; I say it, and most people I hear say it.  (I'm American.)  What surprises me is how many *Americans* say it.  My gut feeling was that it sounded British, since the British accent often replaces *aw* with the *w* vowel (as in *tool*).

Comment: In the US, there is a definite north-south divide, southerners tending toward the former. When I say it like that, I can't help conjuring up a mental image of Foghorn Leghorn.